# Adding a Layout Container for the Android Banner Ad with FAN

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-layout, ads

I'm trying to add facebook audience Banner Ad to an existing project, The documentation provided by facebook at (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/ad-setup/android/banner/) says that this code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/banner_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```

Should be added to `activity_main.xml`, and basically my project doesn't have that layout file.
Where should I integrate that code? so that the banner Ad will be applied on the overall app screens.

Comment: Still no help!!

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet need to be added to your layout xml's. If you have multiple layouts/activities you need to add it for all of them, so that it is visible on all the screens

Comment: I saw some youtubers doing it for only the 'activity_main.xml', and it surprisingly worked for all the app layouts.